# Groovy variable not accessible in java class of same project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

I have a maven java project in eclipse. I added a groovy file in the project having a public variable. I access the groovy variable in another java class but i get compilation error (see below). I have the GRECLIPSE plugin installed. Also via command line when I build the project using mvn it compiles successfully.

How do I resolve this?

Groovy class -

```
package com.impl

class UserConstants {
    public static final String USER_PREFERENCES = 
        """Some value"""
}
```

Java class in the same package. At the import line I get error "The import  cannot be resolved" and due to that I get error at the Sysout line also "USER_PREFERENCES cannot be resolved to a variable"

```
package com.impl

import static com.impl.UserConstants.USER_PREFERENCES;

public class UserPreferences {
    public UserPreferences() {
        System.out.println(USER_PREFERENCES);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. What is the compilation error?

Comment: Of course "cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Is there package visibility? If it's a member variable did you instantiate the class?

Comment: It's impossible to help without more information, probably including the minimum code necessary to duplicate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the project into Groovy project solved the problem